# iOS seems to be bypassing basic server authentication

Tags: objective-c, ios, apache, http, basic-authentication

I'm trying to get my iOS app to access files from my local apache server using basic authentication. Everything works fine from the browser and I have to enter my username and password to access an image in the restricted folder. However in the app some strange things are happening.

I make an NSURLConnection to the server (which is all working fine) and the first time my request is made the delegate method `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge` is called. For test purposes I respond with an empty `NSURLCredential` and obviously the connection fails. However when I make the request again the delegate method isn't called and somehow the image gets downloaded and displayed without any authentication. I'm really confused as to what's going on!

Here is some of the code:

```
- (IBAction)loginPressed
{
    self.username = self.usernameField.text;
    self.password = self.passwordField.text;
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.2/secret/favicon.ico"]];
    self.connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)theConnection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [self.data appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:self.data];
    self.errorLabel.text = @"";
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0) {
        NSURLCredential *newCredential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:self.username password:self.password persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];
        [challenge.sender useCredential:newCredential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    } else {
        [challenge.sender cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        self.errorLabel.text = @"Invalid Username and/or Password";
        self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[[NSData alloc] init]];
    }
}
```

Comment: That's pretty much all the code used. I am sending the requests through a login button and I got the results above when leaving the textfields blank.

Comment: BTW, your last line of code is leaking. You are creating an `NSData` instance without releasing it.  Aside from that, you can just assign the imageView image to `nil`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a different delegate callback, `connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:`.

```
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
    didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {

    if ([challenge previousFailureCount] > 0) {
        // Do something, like prompt for credentials or cancel the connection
    } else {
        NSURLCredential *creds = [NSURLCredential 
                          credentialWithUser:@"someUser" 
                                    password:@"somePassword"
                                 persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];

        [[challenge sender]  useCredential:creds forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
}
```

Comment: I am still confused as to how the application actually managed to download the image without responding to the authentication challenge. Exactly the same issue is occurring with the new delegate method.

Comment: @ruhatch Cached image?  Try downloading a different image.

Comment: Excellent that worked. I have no changed the cache policy on the request to avoid this issue in the future.

Comment: This does not work any more in iOS 8, you should go the willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge way